# elastic apm for c# jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, elastic-apm

I add ElasticAPM to my startup on AspNetCore 3.1

```
app.UseAllElasticApm(Configuration);
```

in my project, rest api services logs as transaction tab of kibana-apm. but my background services dos not logged by apm agent & only metrics tab work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently background services are not captured out of the box.

What you can do is to use the [Public Agent API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/public-api.html) and with a little bit of an additional code you can capture those also as transactions.

Something like this in the background service:

```
var transaction = Elastic.Apm.Agent
        .Tracer.StartTransaction("MyTransaction", ApiConstants.TypeRequest);
try
{
    //background service code that is captured as a transaction
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    transaction?.CaptureException(e);
    throw;
}
finally
{
    transaction?.End();
}
```

Comment: what is TypeRequest? i place this code to startup.cs?

Comment: It's a string that specifies the transaction type - it's in `Elastic.Apm.Api.ApiConstants`, and it's defined as "request". You can put any string there - something like "background-service" could also make sense here. To the second part: " i place this code to startup.cs": no, you please this code into the code where you'd like to capture the transaction - in your case into the background service.

Comment: my background service added as singleton in ConfigureServices. now i place this di configs in try block?

Comment: No, the di config is not relevant here. Based on your question I assume you want to capture the background service. This service has some code... that is the code you'd like to see in Kibana as transaction. Wrap the code you'd like to see into the try block and then it'll show up as a transaction in Kibana under APM. E.g. if your background service has an ExecuteAsync or a DoWork method then wrap the method into a try block similar to above. With this API you can basically programmatically do what the agent itself does automatically for your for the webapi requests.

Comment: in my ExecuteAsync  of my Job i place this apm code. but not log any transaction!

Comment: If you could turn the agent log level to trace and show me the agent logs I can take a look at it - logs could help me to figure this out. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-supportability.html#config-log-level